# .NET1.1 website on IIS7

Tags: iis-7.5

I have just installed windows 7 (IIS7.5) on my development system. I was trying to run my .NET1.1 web applications on it. I have registered .NET1.1, which created an application pool for ASP.NET1.1. The problem I am facing is, when I try to run my 1.1 website using localhost URL, it gives me error **"An unhandled win32 exception occured in w3wp.exe, the just-in-time debugger was launched without necessary security permissions. To debug this process, the just-in-time debugger must be run as an Administrator."**

Process Details, **"Process Name: w3wp.exe, UserName: IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET1.1[Elevated]"**

Can someone help me resolving this error?

Thanks

Comment: Is it giving you a stack trace?

Comment: Nope, just this error in a dialog box.

Comment: Did you check event log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved the problem. Following URL gives step by step instructions for installing and enabling the .NET1.1 on IIS7. Things are little bit different on windows7 but almost similar.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/472/how-to-install-aspnet-11-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008/

The main part is installation of [.NET Framework Version 1.1 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a8f5654f-088e-40b2-bbdb-a83353618b38&DisplayLang=en) 
and then installation of [ASP.NET Security Update for .NET Framework 1.1 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8ec6fb8a-29eb-49cf-9dbc-1a0dc2273ff9&DisplayLang=en)

It resolved my problem as defined in the question of this thread.

Thanks everyone

Comment: I would also add that .NET 1.1 is not officially supported in Windows 2008 R2, so although it works you might have problems when deploying your application in 2008 R2 (Note that 2008 does support it) and support will not help.