# using dot net 1.1 on IIS 7.5 (windows 7 - 32 bit)

Tags: iis-7.5, iis-5, asp.net-1.1

Getting a lot of problems when I am trying to run a .NET 1.1 solution on IIS7.5 (on windows 7, 32 bit system).  When I add the virtual directory in IIS and provide it with an ASP 1.1 application pool and try to browse the site, it adds events to to the event log with event id 5009 and 1000 and stops the application pool. I dont know what is probably going wring here and have been unable to find anything on net. I am thinking to install IIS 5.1 instead (sinse the same project on a xp machine with iis 5.1 works alright). Is it even possible to install IIS 5.1 on windows 7 32 bit system? OR if there is an another solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET1.1 website on IIS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285252/net1-1-website-on-iis7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) .Net1.1 on IIS7.5

Follow this [IIS blog on .Net 1.1](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/06/02/installing-asp-net-1-1-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008.aspx), or this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285252/net1-1-website-on-iis7/3286022#3286022).

2) VS2003 on IIS7.5

Couple of blogs suggest you need .Net 1.1 SP1 and Run VS As Administrator: [here](http://www.hexanes.com/?p=183), [here](http://www.keylimetie.com/Blog/2008/1/17/Using-VS7-in-Vista/), [here](http://tech.einaregilsson.com/2008/01/15/developing-aspnet-1-1-in-visual-studio-2008/), and [here](http://blogs.iis.net/brian-murphy-booth/archive/2007/03/09/how-to-setup-asp-net-v1-1-visual-studio-net-2003-projects-on-iis7-vista.aspx)

Comment: done with all the steps except 3rd one which asks me to do this: Enable ASP.NET v1.1 ISAPI Extension.  How do I do it in Windows 7 (IIS 7.5)? I dont see any add button in actions sidepane when I select CGI or ISAPI icon... thanks for the help so far...

Comment: well its running now with all the changes done. But when I try to open the website code using Visual Studio 2003 it gives me error : Visual studio .NET cannot create or open the application. The likeliest problem is that required components are not installed on the local web server. Run visual studio .NET setup and add the web development component.